# scroll bar issue for default height

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am getting horizontal scroll bar for default height, i tried to change my css properties but its not working. any idea how to solve this issue? my css and html code given below.

### css

```
#content {
position:absolute;
top:40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display:block;
background:#181818 url("../img/bg-charcoal.gif");
overflow: auto;
}
#content-margin {
margin:8px 8px 8px 22px;
}
#content-scroll {
position:relative;
display:block;
min-height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

### HTML

```
    <div id="content">
       <div id="content-scroll">
          <div id="content-margin">
          <!-- content here -- >
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off margin/padding on your body.

http://jsfiddle.net/qj91s5qu/

```
body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I *strongly* reccomend using a reset CSS for ALL your projects: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

A CSS reset will turn off all the browser defaults (which are different across browsers) so there aren't unexpected CSS properties.

Comment: did you also do the same settings for html like in my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. The body has a default value for the body tag.

Add this to your code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
position:relative;
display:block;
min-height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
#content-margin {
margin:8px 8px 8px 22px;
}
#content-scroll {
position:absolute;
top:40px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display:block;
background:#181818 url("../img/bg-charcoal.gif");
overflow: auto;
}
```

just change your css i think the problem is the position: relative and position: absolute;